# Importing two Vaadin embeddables in one static HTML

Tags: vaadin

I am creating a simple POC trying to embed two Vaading apps (Hello World apps) in a static index.html ("index.html" is served by an Nginx in port 8000, and the two "Hello World" aps are server in 8081 and 8082 ports respectively). This is my file importing the first one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="border: 1px solid black">
            <tr>
                <td><tag-hello></tag-hello></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script type='module' src='http://localhost:8081/web-component/tag-hello.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code works as expected. The "Hello World" app is loaded and works well ("Hello World" app has CORS headers enabled).

The problem is that, when I add the second "Hello World" app, only the second is loaded:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="border: 1px solid black">
            <tr>
                <td><tag-hello></tag-hello></td><td><tag-hello2></tag-hello2></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <script type='module' src='http://localhost:8081/web-component/tag-hello.js'></script>
        <script type='module' src='http://localhost:8082/web-component/tag-hello2.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing here? Why the first one is not loaded now?

Comment: What is the browser console telling you? Is the first one on port 8081 receiving a request?

Comment: Yes. I can see the request to get "tag-hello.js" with a 200 response code. Is there something additional that I have to do to import more than one Vaadin Embedable UIs to my static page?

Comment: Have you read this?
https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-embedding
Perhaps you need to embed them as iframes so they don't fight over the browser dom

Comment: Yes, but using iframes is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Is there an error message in the browser's console? That might help understand what's going wrong

Comment: No errors. When I go to "Sources" Tab in Chrome Developer Mode, I can see that only the Vaadin resources on 8082 port has been loaded.

Do you think that this simple use case is a misuse of Vaadin?